# Undefined output when object is missing

Tags: javascript

I will do my best in trying to ask this question as it is a lack of knowledge of knowing what I am looking for to be able to search for it as I am not fluid with JavaScript. I know why it is happening, I am just not sure how to resolve it using JavaScript.

I am parsing and looping through a JSON file from an API response. Sometimes the object NWSHeadline from the below snippet will be included in the file if there is a headline which could be any text as the value or the NWSheadline object could be removed all together from the file if there is not any text to be displayed.

```
 "parameters": {
                    "NWSheadline": [
                        "TEXT VALUE FOR NWSHEADLINE"
                    ],
```

For brevity purposes I am only posting a snippet for the above that is relevant to my issue. In my loop I have the following line that creates the var for the object NWSheadline

```
var NWSheadline = entry.properties.parameters.NWSheadline;
```

So when I place it in my HTML for example...

```
<div class="alerts-description-popover"><p>' + NWSheadline + '</p>
```

It will output the value of that object NWSheadline from the JSON file which could be any text in the form of a sentence, if that NWSHeadline object is present in the file. If the NWSheadline object is not present in the JSON file I am left with just Undefined being outputted because NWSheadline is being declared in my HTML but does not exists in the JSON file. So I know why it is happening now to try to resolve it.

So my question is how would I suppress it showing Undefined in Javascript so that if NWSHeadline isn't available in the JSON it will show nothing instead of Undefined?

Now in PHP which I am much more familiar with I do something like this.

```
$NWSheadline = $currFeature['properties']['parameters']['NWSheadline'][0] ?? null;
```

Is there something similar in JavaScript that will have the same results or some other means of preventing Undefined when the NWSheadline is not present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! You can use the "or" `||` operator.
You can do:

```
var NWSheadline = entry.properties.parameters.NWSheadline || "default value";
```

Is the equivalent of your php line;

EDIT:

Look at this block just too get familiarized with this operator:

```
var has_some_value = "some value!";
var has_undefined;

console.log(has_some_value || "default")
console.log(has_undefined || "default")
```

you can see as result:

```
> some value!
> default
```

Now, let's see in your case, you can test just pasting in console:

```
var entry = {
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "NWSheadline": [
                "TEXT VALUE FOR NWSHEADLINE"
            ]
        }
    }
}

var NWSheadline = entry.properties.parameters.NWSheadline || "default value";

console.log(NWSheadline);


var entry2 = {
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "some_other_things": 123
        }
    }
}

var NWSheadline2 = entry2.properties.parameters.NWSheadline || "default value";

console.log(NWSheadline2);
```

Here we have `entry` with `NWSheadline` and `entry2` with `NWSheadline2`.
The output:

```
> ["TEXT VALUE FOR NWSHEADLINE"]
> default value
```

Hope it may help

Comment: Maybe my logic is off or I am missing something. If I try this `var NWSheadline = entry.properties.parameters.NWSheadline || "";` It still outputs undefined as the value if the object NWSheadline is missing from the JSON file. Maybe I am looking in the wrong place to fix this?

Comment: I've edited my answer to try make it clearer, hope it helps!
If you're still seeing 'undefined', I'll double check de var names and put some console.log's to see the the values if you're not familiar with debugs.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. This indeed does work. `var NWSheadline = entry.properties.parameters.NWSheadline || "";` I was editing my back up file instead of my beta file which is why I wasn't seeing the change.